# Saving text in QComboBox to SQL table

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I need to be able to update Sql records from a combobox's contents. I am using a tableview to retrieve existing rows and populate comboboxes and qlinedit's.
When I alter the comboboxes and try to write their new state back to the database, they are not saved. I can't see any obvious problems in the code but any help is greatly appreciated.

example code:

```
// used to edit current database row

 void Financelog::on_pushButton_Edit_clicked()
 {
 MainWindow conn;

 QString BANK_MNTH, BUSN_MNGR, NEW_USED, APP_APPR;

 BANK_MNTH=ui->txt_BANK_MNTH->text();
 BUSN_MNGR=ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->text();  
 NEW_USED=ui->comboBox_newused->currentText();
 APP_APPR=ui->comboBox_approved->currentText();

 if(!conn.connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Failed to open database";
    return;
}

QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("update STOCK set BANK_MNTH='"+BANK_MNTH+"',BUSN_MNGR='"+BUSN_MNGR+"',NEW_USED='"+NEW_USED+"',APP_APPR='"+APP_APPR+"'");
if(qry.exec( ))
 {
 QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Update"),tr("Record Updated"));
 QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();
 QSqlQuery* qry2=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
 qry2->prepare("select top 100 DEAL_NUMB, BUSN_MNGR, BANK_MNTH, NEW_USED, APP_APPR");  
 qry2->exec();
 modal->setQuery(*qry2);
 ui->tableView->setModel(modal);
 foreach(QLineEdit *Financelog, this->findChildren<QLineEdit*>()) {
    Financelog->clear();
 }
 }
else
{
  QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
}
}


// pre-fills Qlinedits when double clicking on the tableview index

void Financelog::on_tableView_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
QString val=ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();

MainWindow conn;
if(!conn.connOpen())
{

    qDebug()<<"Failed to open database";
    return;
}
QSqlQuery qry;

qry.prepare("select top 100 DEAL_NUMB, BANK_MNTH, BUSN_MNGR, NEW_USED, APP_APPR from STOCK where DEAL_NUMB ='"+val+"'");

if(qry.exec( ))
{
    while(qry.next())
    {
        ui->txt_DEAL_NUMB->setText(qry.value(0).toString());
        ui->txt_BANK_MNTH->setText(qry.value(1).toString());
        ui->txt_BUSN_MNGR->setText(qry.value(2).toString());
        ui->comboBox_approved->setCurrentText(qry.value(25).toString());
        ui->comboBox_newused->setCurrentText(qry.value(28).toString());
    }      
}
else
{
  QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error::"),qry.lastError().text());
}
}
```

Comment: also tried "qry.bindValue("app", APP_APPR=ui->comboBox_approved->currentText());" but the same problem persists...

Comment: Very strange code. Can you show your ui layout? How that table looks. And where your combobox.

Comment: Sorry, the code I provided is cut down as an example, hence some of the oddities like missing the where id = '"+id+"' at the end of the SQL query, and the qry.value()'s not having sequential numbers. Still, any idea why the combobox contents are not being correctly stored in the QString variables?

Comment: I just not see any code that should save value to table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In good case you should implement your "delegate" for table, that will show editor in table cells. This shall be children of **QSyledItemDelegate** class. You'll save data to DB via QSyledItemDelegate::setModelData() method.

Comment: This approach will hard for you. But when understand it once.  You can show anything in table cells.